# Restar 3 días a una fecha con SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

lo que pasa es que estoy leyendo las respuestas y no me funciona ninguna.

Estoy trabajando en SQL ORACLE y tengo una variable que me devuelve una fecha de la siguiente forma
`Array_fecha_form := 16-02-2024` y necesito restarle 3 días, estos 3 días me llegan en una variable de este Date así:
`numdia_habil = 03-02-2024`

cuando las resto me sale un valor negativo y muy largo

`var FECHA_ENVIO_REVISORIA:=  to_date(Array_fecha_form.get(0),'dd') - to_date(numdia_habil,'dd') ;`

salida es -145338368 lo cual no es lo esperado, debería ser 13-02-2024

anexo el codigo completo

```
  var dateFormat := new("java.text.SimpleDateFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy");
  var dateFormat2 := new("java.text.SimpleDateFormat", "MM-yyyy");
  var dateFormatDay := new("java.text.SimpleDateFormat", "dd");
  var fechaEjecucion := dateFormat2.format(ASOF_DATE);

  var dia_a_restar := to_date('01-03-2024');
  var numdia_habil:= dateFormatDay.format(dia_a_restar) +'-' fechaEjecucion;

  var Array_fecha     := List();
  var Array_fecha_form := List();

  Array_fecha := (select("SELECT FECHA_VENCIMIENTO FROM " + sourceTableLatest("fuente[nombre_Objeto]")));

  <for> var j = 0 <comma/> j &lt; Array_fecha.size() <comma/> j++  
      <do>
        Array_fecha_form.add(dateFormat.format(Array_fecha.get(j)));            
        
      </do>
  </for>    

  trace('#### FECHA_VENCIMIENTO_FORMATEADA: '+ Array_fecha_form);
  trace('#### FECHA_VENCIMIENTO_FORMATEADA: '+ Array_fecha_form.get(0));  
  trace('#### DIAS a restar: '+ numdia_habil );


var FECHA_ENVIO_REVISORIA :=  to_date(Array_fecha_form.get(0)) - numdia_habil ;
trace('###### fecha envio a revisoria: '+ FECHA_ENVIO_REVISORIA );


salida:
#### FECHA_VENCIMIENTO_FORMATEADA: [16-02-2024, 16-02-2024, 15-02-2024, 16-02-2024, 22-02-2024, 20-02-2024] 
#### FECHA_VENCIMIENTO_FORMATEADA: 16-02-2024 
#### DIAS a restar: 03-02-2024 
#### fecha envio a revisoria: -145338368 

si convierto la salida en TO_DATE trace('###### fecha envio a revisoria: '+ TO_DATE(FECHA_ENVIO_REVISORIA,'dd-MM-yyyy') );

ME SALE ###### fecha envio a revisoria: Tue Dec 30 02:37:41 COT 1969
```

Osea no se por que al restar se resta hasta el año 1989

Comment: estas transformando los dos a dias??? sera por eso??

Comment: ¿De qué tipo son las variables? Si son Date, las fechas en Oracle se encierran en comillas, es mejor que publiques código real, para evitar errores involuntarios al publicarlo. Finalmente, cómo sabes que la variable `numdia_habil` significa 3 días y no otra cosa, si lo que lleva es una fecha?

Comment: ya agregué el código completo. En una lista estoy agregando varias fechas, pero pa la prueba al final solo cojo la primera fecha de la lista y le quiero restar 3 días

Comment: ¿Y el formato de fecha al imprimir su valor? Aparte de eso: no entiendo por qué estás restando una fecha en lugar de la cantidad de días...

Comment: El código que publica es de Java, entonces porque habla de restar días con SQL Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

por lo que veo to cast a to_date le faltan argumentos:

debes ser asi:

```
to_date(string,format)
```

por lo que la fecha debe ir

```
to_date('16-02-2024','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

donde la

- **DD** es dia del mes
- **MM** es mes
- **YYYY** es ano de 4 digitos

y ejemplo:

```
select to_date('16-02-2024','DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date('03-02-2024','DD-MM-YYYY')  from dual;
```

resultado:

```
TO_DATE('16-02-2024','DD-MM-YYYY')-TO_DATE('03-02-2024','DD-MM-YYYY')
---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                   13
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre encontrar el problema y era que la fecha de entrada llegaba en formato 'dd-MMM-yyyy' y yo estaba leyendo como 'dd-mm-yyyy', por tal motivo fallaba
'''
codigo antes
var dateFormat := new("java.text.SimpleDateFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy");

codigo despues
var dateFormat := new("java.text.SimpleDateFormat", "dd-MMM-yyyy");'''